# Nested async-await while using node js

Tags: node.js, async-await, nested

I have been stuck while trying to implement the following folder/code structure using nested async-await routines in Node.JS.

Seems this approach is creating some problems for Node.JS and the execution seems to fail and calling arbitrary routines.

```js
//main.js
const main = async () => {
    let data = await foo(a, b)
    //Continue processing
};

//foo.js
const foo = async (a, b) => {
    const x = a - 10; const y = b + 10; //do some arbitrary data manipulation here
    let data = await bar(x, y);
    return data;
};

//bar.js
const bar = async (c, d) => {
    let data = await c.save();  //assume c is a mongoose object (eg; user)
    return data;
};
```

The above code does not return the saved record from the db. Is a nested `async-await` supported in Node.JS?

I do significant pre & post processing in both of the called routines.

Answer (score -1):

Caused by memory leaks, I believe. Declaring a number of variables potentially caused heap/stack? issues that caused the chaotic behavior. Putting all variables into a single object solved the issue, this time. Interesting find!